# Wrap content for List View layout width has no desired effect

Tags: android, xml

Setting wrap_content for the ListView 's width has no effect. The ListView covers the whole screen horizontally.
Can any one help me with the reason behind the effect.

Answer (score 0):

```
wrap_content
```

Take the required width to wrap the children.

It is because the listView children are occupying the complete screen width,which will make the listView width be the width of the child that has the largest width. hence wrap_content won't work until all your children have less width than the screen width.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Ho wdo you say that the listView children are occupying the complete screen width. I have a text with 5 letters in it and the width for it is again wrap content.

Comment: there is a layout in which your textView is wrapped in, it must have got fill_parent.

Comment: Yashwant i have set all the params for child as wrap content too. Can you try out your inputs in a test application for list view and confirm.

Comment: are you using custom layout for each row in listView?